# How to minimize current activity and resume previous one?

Tags: android, android-activity, minimize

During research I found this code.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
         {
            this.moveTaskToBack(true);

            return true;
         }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Calling Activity like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
                                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                i.putExtra("IN_ROOMID", roomId);
                                i.putExtra("IN_USERID", from);
                                startActivity(i);
```

But above code minimize entire application that I don't want actually.

**What is my requirement?**

Suppose I have two activities say **ActivityOne.java** and **ActivityTwo.java**.

ActivityOne -> **calls** -> ActivityTwo

If I press **back** button in **ActivityTwo** it should be **minimize** and **ActivityOne** should **resume**.

Hos to achieve this.
Thanks.
Biraj Zalavadia.

Comment: and you cannot call `finish()`? why not? you can easily save the state, and the next time it is opened you restore it. I think it is easy and reliable

Comment: How did you start ActivityTwo from ActivityOne?

Answer (score 1):

As, there is no concept of minimize explicitly. you can make ActivityOne single instance, and from ActivityTwo, start ActivityOne, ActivityTwo by default will go in background (minimized). what say you?